# When opening new terminal window, how to tell it to open full screen?

Tags: gnome-terminal

Just as in the title. I find myself often opening new terminal window (not tab) from terminal. Is there a way to specify so that the new window opens maximized?

I looked at -geometry option, but only found a way to set the offsets with it, and not how to tell it to me maximized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create or modify your shortcut with the following command:

```
gnome-terminal --window --maximize
```

Which will force it to open maximized.